# In a 13 card HILO game, without suit, how this betting website calculates the odds of having an ACE at certain time? Link Sample.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a 13 card HILO game, without suit, how this betting website calculates the odds of having an ACE at certain time before the game ends? Link Sample.

Im quite curious how the side bets odds are calculated on this website as i was making a copy of it... How are these calculated? I seriusly tried to calculate it but i cannot for the life of me.  My probability classes now are long behind me :)

http://games.betfair.com/exchange-hi-lo/turbo/ 
And click the side bets pane.

This is an exchange so the wbsite should have no interest in having fake odds.

All help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: By knowing how many aces are left after certain cards have been played.

Comment: There is only one ace to be played, the issue is, at every turn a new card is taken, Above or Below the previous card, thus ending the game before time. So my guess is that this has to be factored into the solution.